# How to go to a new line in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

I want to write a function, something like this

```
double :: Int -> Int
double x = x + x
```

The problem is that after I write the first line:

```
Prelude> double :: Int -> Int
```

I try to go to the next line pressing the enter key, but when I do I get:

```
<interactive>:84:1: Not in scope: `double'
Prelude>
```

It seems that the program executes the first line, but I dont want that, I want the program to let me write the second line and only then compile and execute

So, how can I go to the next line in Haskell (Im using the Terminal on Mac OS)?

Comment: With ghci, a better way to write haskell code is to edit a file and use :load and :reload.  This way you avoid retyping after every mistake.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In ghci, you have to put definitions on a single line, and also begin them with `let` (EDIT: you don't have to start ghci definitions with `let` anymore).  It's different than in a source file:

```
ghci> let double :: Int -> Int; double x = x + x
```

You can also use `:{` and `:}` to do a muli-line definition:

```
ghci> :{
Prelude| let double :: Int -> Int
Prelude|     double x = x + x
Prelude| :}
ghci> double 21
42
```

Make sure to indent the second `double` to line up with the first one -- indentation is significant.

I recommend doing most of your work in a text editor, and then load the file into ghci (with `:load`, or providing it as an argument on the command line) and playing with it.  I don't find ghci terribly pleasant to work with when actually writing code -- it's much better at messing around with code that's already written. Whenever you modify the text file, `:reload` (or just `:r`) in ghci.